# Handle multiple URLs from Open With in SwiftUI on Mac

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

In SwiftUI we have been given the [onOpenURL(perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/onOpenURL(perform:)) function. However, in macOS we can select multiple files in Finder and click on Open With. If I open these files with an app with code such as:

```
@main
struct testURLMacApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    print("RECEIVED \(url)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

it appears this function does not work properly for multiple files. It appears to sometimes to call the perform closure once, or sometimes if lucky 2-3 times max in succession. Sometimes it appears to do weird things like open a duplicate app window.

Has anyone found out a workaround for this, or the proper way of handling opening multiple files in a single window in a SwiftUI app?

EDIT: This is actually for making an existing iOS app work on Apple Sillicon Macs. So AppKit is not available.

Comment: If you can get the urls, you can use a loop with [openURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/openurl#), or [NSWorkspace.open](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1533463-open).

Answer (score 7):

As described (see below) it registers handler for external events, but uses only first to create new scene (maybe due to limitations, maybe bug, maybe intentionally, who knows...)

[image: demo1]

so if we have `.onOpenURL` that registered handler captures one URL and create new scene for it, others are remains unhandled and received in `AppDelegate` (see below). If we remove `.onOpenURL` completely, all opened URLs from Finder transferred to AppDelegate.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.4

in App

```
@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
    // needed because WindowGroup scene seems have default
    // handler for external events, so opens new scene even
    // if no onOpenURL or userActivity callbacks are present
    .handlesExternalEvents(matching: [])   // << here !!
}
```

and delegate

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL]) {
        print("Unhandled: \(urls)")    // << here !!
    }
}
```

[Compelete test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_macOS/PlayOn_macOS/PlayOn_macOSApp.swift)

Comment: Thank you - this seems to work, albeit splitting the URL's into two callbacks for some reason, guess it could be debounced. A bigger problem though, is I neglected to mention I'm actually trying to make an iOS app work ok on Apple Sillicon ("Designed for iPad"). I changed the NSApplicationDelegate to UIApplicationDelegate and so on, but it causes it to not work at all. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: well, you tagged [macos], but talk about catalyst, that's absolutely two different worlds.

Comment: @SteveM You probably need to implement openURL in the scene delegate, because multi-window iOS apps do that stuff at the scene level not the app level. Here’s how to add a UISceneDelegate to a SwiftUI app: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/app-delegate-scene-delegate-swiftui

Comment: @Adam I tried your suggestion for iOS and the app is calling the scene `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)` but still only passes a single URL.  If anybody has other suggestions please post.

Comment: @GerryShaw, did you even find a fix for this?

Comment: @ChidiWilliams, nope. I ended up working around the problem by supporting a ZIP of multiple files to be imported as single URL. Obviously not ideal for most uses but in my case it is working.

Comment: Thank you! This was really the missing element to make drop / open file urls work without opening new windows when having to make it work with WindowGroup in macOS 12.